# Visual Studio 2010: adding a service reference to a 2008 generated wsdl

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

Doesn't produce a app.config . In my team there is a guy who has Visual Studio 2008, he created a webservice.

Then there is me, adding this webservice to a console project.

Adding the service reference goes without problems but no valid app.config is generated. It's just empty

```
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

When I disable 'reuse types' in my service reference it works but then I get an ambiguous error.

Is this a bug?

I found [Visual Studio does not generate app.config content when "add service reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159107/visual-studio-does-not-generate-app-config-content-when-add-service-reference) this one, but there is no solution there, so I thought I bump the problem up again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue with Visual Studio 2008. I find I get different results if I'm using the "Add Service Reference..." command, or digging deeper to "Add Service Reference..." | "Advanced..." | "Add Web Reference...".

However, the tried-and-true method--and the solution that worked for me--is still via the command line:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:GeneratedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://server/path_to/WebServiceBean?WSDL
```

That should give you a working `app.config`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is the same answer as [Visual Studio does not generate app.config content when "add service reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159107/visual-studio-does-not-generate-app-config-content-when-add-service-reference/12034326#12034326) duplicated to save cross referencing:

When adding the service reference try clicking on the 'Advanced...' button and then uncheck the 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' checkbox.

I found this out when I had created a simple project to test a third party service which all worked fine. Attempting to add the same reference to the main project resulted in the app.config and reference.vb file not being generated correctly.

I think this may have been because there were already other web references in the application or referenced applications, however unchecking 'Reuse types' resulted in the files being generated correctly.